# Disable plugins for a specific user role

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I found this plugin and it disable plugins for users who are logged in,
how can I change it to make disable plugins for contributor user role only?

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_logged_in_plugin' );

function disable_logged_in_plugin( $plugins ) {

    // The 'option_active_plugins' hook occurs before any user information get generated,
    // so we need to require this file early to be able to check for logged in status
    require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');

    // If we are logged in, and not inside the WP Admin area
    if ( is_user_logged_in() & !is_admin() ) {

        // Use the plugin folder and main file name here.
        // is used here as an example
           $plugins_not_needed = array ('embed-image-links/embed-image-links.php',
           'external-featured-image/main.php','wp-noexternallinks/wp-noexternallinks.php' );
            foreach ( $plugins_not_needed as $plugin ) {
                $key = array_search( $plugin, $plugins );
                if ( false !== $key ) {
                    unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        return $plugins;
    }
```

Comment: `is_admin()` doesn't test if you're an administrator, it tests if you're in the admin area, the same way `is_home`, `is_archive`. and `is_single` work. `is_admin` will return true for a subscriber looking at WP Admin, and false for a super admin on the frontend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. I just changed only `current_user_can('contributor')` instead of `is_user_logged_in()`.

```
add_filter( 'option_active_plugins', 'disable_logged_in_plugin' );

function disable_logged_in_plugin( $plugins ) {

    // The 'option_active_plugins' hook occurs before any user information get generated,
    // so we need to require this file early to be able to check for logged in status
    require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');

    // If we are logged in, and NOT an admin...
    if ( current_user_can('contributor') & !is_admin() ) {

        // Use the plugin folder and main file name here.
        // is used here as an example
           $plugins_not_needed = array ('embed-image-links/embed-image-links.php',
           'external-featured-image/main.php','wp-noexternallinks/wp-noexternallinks.php' );
            foreach ( $plugins_not_needed as $plugin ) {
                $key = array_search( $plugin, $plugins );
                if ( false !== $key ) {
                    unset( $plugins[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        return $plugins;
    }
```

Comment: Does a "role" work here? Contributes is a role not a capability right?

Comment: Never mind, it checks out ;)

Comment: Nice find! `require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');` was all I needed :) Edit: seems like that was in the question already. Oh well upvotes for everyone!